# xslt: substring-before when node contains ampersand

Tags: xslt-2.0

I´m new with xslt and need to transform some xml to another schema. To avoid having ampersands in my xml, I simply need to cut the string before the first amp (if there is any in the special node). So I tried to test if there is an amp and if so, cut before amp.

The XML looks like this:

```
    <record>
      <field MIDAS="#DocumentKey">obj     00004348</field>
      <field MIDAS="#5000">00004348</field>
      <field MIDAS="#5001"/>
      <field MIDAS="#5007[0]"/>
      <field MIDAS="#5007[0].5008"/>
      <field MIDAS="#5060[0]">Herstellung</field>
      <field MIDAS="#5060[0].5064">1948-1956 &amp; 1966-1968</field>
      <field MIDAS="#5060 [Umbau etc]"/>
    </record>
    <record>
      <field MIDAS="#DocumentKey">obj     00000002</field>
      <field MIDAS="#5000">00000002</field>
      <field MIDAS="#5001"/>
      <field MIDAS="#5007[0]">Teil von</field>
      <field MIDAS="#5007[0].5008">00000077</field>
      <field MIDAS="#5060[0]">Herstellung</field>
      <field MIDAS="#5060[0].5064">1904-1905</field>
      <field MIDAS="#5060 [Umbau etc]"/>
    </record>
    ...


This is my code for one of many datafields:

    <xsl:apply-templates select="field[@MIDAS='#ob45[0].4600' and .!='']"/>
...
<!--Field mappings-->
    <xsl:template match="field[@MIDAS='#ob45[0].4600']">
        <datafield tag="510" ind1=" " ind2=" ">
            <subfield code="a">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="contains(field[@MIDAS='#ob45[0].4600'],'&amp;')">
                        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before('./', '&amp;')"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </subfield>
            <subfield code="4">rela</subfield>
            <subfield code="4">https://d-nb.info/standards/elementset/gnd#relatedCorporateBody</subfield>
            <subfield code="i">In Beziehung stehende Körperschaft</subfield>
            <subfield code="9">
                <xsl:text>v:</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="../field[@MIDAS='#ob45[0] Sozietaet']"/>
            </subfield>
        </datafield>
    </xsl:template>

The result for subfield code="a": 

    <subfield code="a">1948-1956 &amp; 1966-1968</subfield>

Why does the substring-before does not work and I still have the ampersands? In some records there are amps, in other not, so I need to test.

I need:

    <subfield code="a">1948-1956</subfield>
```

Comment: You haven't shown what the input looks like, so it's difficult to diagnose without guessing. Provide an example of what the XML looks like that is producing the result you posted.

Comment: Are you sure you want `substring-before('./', '&amp;')`? That is calling `substring-before` on the input string `'./'`. Anyway, it looks as if that doesn't make much sense, but I second Mads' request to show some samples to allow others to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I added a snippet of my xml

Comment: You should post minimal but complete samples to allow others to reproduce the problem. Showing the test `<xsl:when test="contains(field[@MIDAS='#5060[0].5064'],'&amp;')">` without any context doesn't allow anyone to tell whether the test makes sense.

Comment: another try...sorry I´m really a beginner

Answer (score 0):

Inside of any template the matched node is the context node so with `<xsl:template match="field[@MIDAS='#ob45[0].4600']">` that `field` element is the context node, your attempt at doing `<xsl:when test="contains(field[@MIDAS='#ob45[0].4600'],'&amp;')">` tries to select a `field` child element of the context item, which would only make sense if your `field`s were nested.

So you simply want `<xsl:when test="contains(.,'&amp;')">` and of course then process e.g. `<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., '&amp;')"/>` and not `<xsl:value-of select="substring-before('./', '&amp;')"/>` (which tries to apply `substring-before` on the string literal `'./'`).